# I have been feeling increasingly lethargic and unfocused and experience brain fog and fatigue. Should I resign and accept a new job despite how I feel

Tags: resignation, sickness, job-acceptance

I have been feeling increasingly  ill for the past several months: fatigue, brain fog, body aches. The symptoms are better some days, worse on others. Stress makes the symptoms worse. My doctor has been trying to determine the cause of my symptoms with no success (I’ve had blood work, mris, etc). I’m beginning to think this may be a physical manifestation of severe depression.

While I like the people at my current job, I am not satisfied. Management had made promises last year to keep me from quitting (increased salary, reduced client load by Q2 of this year so that i can focus on new responsibilities which I preferred to transactional work) They ended up giving me a large bonus instead of adding it to my base salary and I had to twist their arms to take some clients away after following up for months. I am now truly beyond tired of the transactional work and I’m disillusioned with management. I am having an extremely difficult time getting my work done. So much so that I felt I needed to alert hr and my immediate manager that I’m having medical problems. Finances are also a large stressor. After 16 years of being drastically underpaid, I need to start making more money.

I wasn’t looking for a new job but an offer with 25% more pay and good benefits has fallen into my lap. The role is similar but with less transactional work, more responsibilities that I prefer. I would have to go into the office 1-2 times per week (versus working remotely full time at the current job). I haven’t seen the office yet but I met with three senior people including the CEO over lunch and got  a really good vibe.

I should note that I’ve been at my current job for 6 years this is only my second job since college (previous job was 10 years). I didn’t think this would be a good time to change jobs because of my “illness” but maybe I mostly need a change to reinvigorate myself? I feel like if I stay at my current job I’ll very soon end up taking FMLA time but I’m also worried that the new job won’t help. Also how should I handle resigning from my old job now that my current company knows I’m not feeling well? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - on the other hand, job stresses absolutely can cause depression and physical issues.  For more pay, and no obvious red flags, why not make a change to see if it helps?

Comment: Please see a physician to rule out any underlying medical condition that may be causing this especially before you make any career moves that you might regret later.

Comment: I immediately thought of Vitamin D deficiency when you mentioned the symptoms. Depression was the second thought as it can also cause these symptoms (many people don't understand that depression can also cause physical symptoms). As @jwh20 said please find a good doctor and rule these out.

Answer (score 9):

Stress is a killer.

If you need to take time off, do it sooner, rather than later.

[THIS ANSWER](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/95896/how-can-i-move-past-being-burnt-out-when-working-long-hours/95912#95912) sums up what happens when you ignore the signs of burnout

Answer (score 9):

-- (Full disclosure: I once volunteered on a suicide-prevention hotline. It was an eye-opening experience.)

I ***very strongly*** advise you to *immediately* consult other physicians.

Go ahead and consult a *clinical psychologist* as well as general practitioners.

Above all, consider that this might be a ***physical*** problem.  And that you, being on the *inside,* are **not** in the best position to understand it.  Your point-of-view is clouded, and that can be very dangerous.    Please do not attempt to 'self-diagnose.'

*"The most amazing thing about the human brain is that the damned thing works at all."*  The whole thing works on micro-chemistry ... profound effects caused by the ingestion of a quantity of LSD that fit on a postage stamp.  Or – I kid you not – a person who eventually traced profound mental effects to an allergy for **broccoli.**  *"You are what you eat,"* and sometimes the effects of nutritional deficiency or allergy can be profound.

"From the inside, looking out," you might not see it – *and* you might not realize that your own mind is now "playing tricks on you."  But a trained outsider can detect the signs, and help you.

Don't throw your job away – not yet.  Get help.  *From professionally-trained perspectives other than your own.*  And, **do not delay.**

Comment: +1 for consulting a psychologist. It sounds to me like the new job will be more enjoyable and less stressful. If your symptoms are primarily due to stress, the new job may resolve them. However, even if this is the perfect job for you, the stress of starting a new job may cause your symptoms to get worse before they get better. A psychologist can help you during the transition.

Comment: +1 for the whole answer. *Get help and fast*. The earlier you find the cause, the better for current and future prospects.

Answer (score 3):

25% more pay, better tasks and good vibes vs arm bending, false promises and menial work.

You should be asking yourself why should I stay? By the sounds of it, it is a good time to change jobs regardless if you are ill or not.

you never know, maybe a fresh start is just what you need to get out of your rut.

Answer (score 2):

> I am not satisfied ... finances are also a large stressor... an offer with 25% more pay and good benefits ... I would have to go into the office 1-2 times per week ...

There's [numerous](https://fortune.com/2021/09/07/everyone-quitting-their-jobs-right-now-2021-covid-great-resignation/#:%7E:text=Employers%20looking%20to%20stop%20the,reflection%20about%20one%27s%20job%20satisfaction.) [reasons](https://www.npr.org/2021/06/24/1007914455/as-the-pandemic-recedes-millions-of-workers-are-saying-i-quit#:%7E:text=As%20pandemic%20life%20recedes%20in%20the%20U.S.%2C%20people%20are%20leaving%20their%20jobs%20in%20search%20of%20more%20money%2C%20more%20flexibility%20and%20more%20happiness.) [why](https://www.inc.com/marcel-schwantes/why-are-people-quitting-burnouts-just-tip-of-iceberg.html) people are leaving their current jobs. The largest issues facing employees today is job satisfaction, better pay, and flexibility / remote work. This new job seems like it will address two of those while, depending, the commute may be problem.

To get to the root of the question though:

- Do you feel energized about the prospect of a new office and new
  challenges?
- Do you feel your current office can change to address your concerns?
- Would a pay bump alleviate some stress, however minor?

Personally, money alleviates a lot of problems in life and you'll never know if there's an improvement unless you take that first step.

How to resign after making them aware of a potential illness, though? As normal: "I've accepted a new position..."

Answer (score 0):

Do multiple things at once to resolve your underlying problems. Take the new job; your whole post makes it clear that this is best and that you want to. Concurrently, do other things to resolve your possible depression and/or physical symptoms. Get exercise, evaluate your sleep hygiene, evaluate your diet, make time for friends and diversions, etc. Upon switching jobs, take a break if you can.